# Single Entry for Remote Data Annotation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I can only have one single Remote Annotation per property??

```
[Remote("CumstomValidationMethod1", "MyValidationController")]
[Remote("CumstomValidationMethod2", "MyValidationController")]

public string MyField { get; set; }
```

Gives me a Duplicate 'Remote' Attribute.

I had to merge the logic for the two methods in order for it to work.

Checked the overloads for Remote... none accommodate. Multiple fields is not what I'm looking for either.

Comment: Is this being used to validate the same field on different pages with different purposes? So on page A you want to validate MyField with one validation method and on page B you want to validate MyField with another validation method.

Comment: No. One page. Multiple custom validators.